# How to made a loop per sequences?

Tags: r

I tried to use a loop for() to predict all my datas with ARIMA, however I got an error.

See the following script :

```
library(forecast)

Exval<-c("CLI", "SPY", "USDEUR", "CPI", "CONSCONF", "FEDFUNDS", "HOUST", "UNRATE", "INDPRO", "VIX")
fcst<-c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

for(i in Exval)
  {for (y in fcst){
    fit_arima<-auto.arima(DATA$i,d=1,D=1,stepwise = FALSE,approximation = FALSE, trace = TRUE)
    y<-forecast(fit_arima,h=36)
    print(summary(y))}}
```

`Error in ts(x) : 'ts' object must have one or more observations`

In my opinion, error comes from i. The loop instantly do next i whereas many observations have to be made on the same i.
For example, when I do not use a loop, outcome is :

```
> fit_arima<-auto.arima(DATA$VIX,d=1,D=1,stepwise = FALSE,approximation = FALSE, trace = TRUE)

 ARIMA(0,1,0)                    : 2017.494
 ARIMA(0,1,0) with drift         : 2019.493
 ARIMA(0,1,1)                    : 2014.853
 ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift         : 2016.861
 ARIMA(0,1,2)                    : 1997.6
 ARIMA(0,1,2) with drift         : 1999.6
 ARIMA(0,1,3)                    : 1991.777
 ARIMA(0,1,3) with drift         : 1993.766
 ARIMA(0,1,4)                    : 1992.797
 ARIMA(0,1,4) with drift         : 1994.786
 ARIMA(0,1,5)                    : 1994.604
 ARIMA(0,1,5) with drift         : 1996.598
 ARIMA(1,1,0)                    : 2016.692
 ARIMA(1,1,0) with drift         : 2018.701
 ARIMA(1,1,1)                    : 1990.448
 ARIMA(1,1,1) with drift         : 1992.359
 ARIMA(1,1,2)                    : 1989.871
 ARIMA(1,1,2) with drift         : 1991.819
 ARIMA(1,1,3)                    : 1991.932
 ARIMA(1,1,3) with drift         : 1993.892
 ARIMA(1,1,4)                    : 1993.856
 ARIMA(1,1,4) with drift         : 1995.819
 ARIMA(2,1,0)                    : 2007.087
 ARIMA(2,1,0) with drift         : 2009.103
 ARIMA(2,1,1)                    : 1989.959
 ARIMA(2,1,1) with drift         : 1991.912
 ARIMA(2,1,2)                    : 1991.932
 ARIMA(2,1,2) with drift         : 1993.894
 ARIMA(2,1,3)                    : Inf
 ARIMA(2,1,3) with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(3,1,0)                    : 2002.725
 ARIMA(3,1,0) with drift         : 2004.75
 ARIMA(3,1,1)                    : 1991.889
 ARIMA(3,1,1) with drift         : 1993.845
 ARIMA(3,1,2)                    : Inf
 ARIMA(3,1,2) with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(4,1,0)                    : 2002.643
 ARIMA(4,1,0) with drift         : 2004.677
 ARIMA(4,1,1)                    : 1993.877
 ARIMA(4,1,1) with drift         : 1995.839
 ARIMA(5,1,0)                    : 2002.835
 ARIMA(5,1,0) with drift         : 2004.879



 Best model: ARIMA(1,1,2)
```

Then I would like to ask you how can I made a loop regarding sequences of observations.

Thank you in advance.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to a column of a data frame using `DATA$i` where `i` is a string.  Instead use `DATA[[i]]` to extract the column as a vector.

Comment: Thank you George ! And what's about my second loop with "y" referring to the integers in list fcst ? I would like to attribute the values predicted on each of these integers in fcst and then work with them. However, when I try to get this one by `print(summary(1))` error is "object '1' not found...

Comment: you are using `y` both to index the loop and to store the result.  I am not sure what you are intending to do here but this cannot be correct.  also i do not understand what you are using the loop index for, since the model and the forcast calls do not depend on `y`